Unable to get old and new rule id on dragNdrop
import { QueryBuilderDnD } from '@react-querybuilder/dnd'; 
import * as ReactDnD from 'react-dnd'; 
import * as ReactDndHtml5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend'; 
import { add, QueryBuilder, formatQuery } from 'react-querybuilder'; 

I am using these query builder and I am using this twice in code
<QueryBuilderDnD dnd={{ ...ReactDnD, ...ReactDndHtml5Backend }}> 
    <QueryBuilder {...prop} > 
    </QueryBuilder> 
</QueryBuilderDnD > 

<QueryBuilderDnD dnd={{ ...ReactDnD, ...ReactDndHtml5Backend }}> 
    <QueryBuilder {...prop} > 
    </QueryBuilder> 
</QueryBuilderDnD > 

so when I drag a query from one to another QueryBuilder I want to get previous and updated rule ID of dragged rule not the query builder id only the rule id which is draged and droped
I am not able to find any handleDrop, isDroped, onDragEnd kind of prop for any of this to get these values
Reproduction:
Create 2 in a single component and move rule from one to another
Expected behavior:
There should be a prop which returns me which rule id is changed and return me old and new id of that rule on dragging from one QueryBuilder to another QueryBuilder
